# 1Password 3 toolbar button not available in Safari 4 on Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, safari

I use 1Password, and it's not an exaggeration to say that I depend on it to manage my passwords. Since installing Snow Leopard (both at home and at work), I switched over to 1Password 3, since 1Password 2 doesn't work in 64-bit mode.  FWIW, I understand that 1Password 3 is still in beta, so some quirky behavior is to be expected.  It's the inconsistency that makes this strange, though.

See, on my MacBook at work, no problems at all.  The 1Password toolbar button shows up every time and works great.

But on my MacBook Pro at home, it used to be that the 1Password toolbar button wouldn't appear in the Safari 4 toolbar (it appeared in Firefox 3.5 just fine), so I had to manually add it to the toolbar (via View->Customize Toolbar) every time I launched Safari.  When I quit Safari, the 1Password toolbar button would be removed from the toolbar, so I had to re-add it every time.  I'm not sure why this happened, but I considered it a minor annoyance, so I didn't worry about it too much.

But now I've upgraded to the most recent 1Password build, and its toolbar button no longer even appears as an available button in the Customize Toolbar menu.  So I'm stuck without 1Password in Safari (but again, still available consistently and works flawlessly in Firefox).

What's the story?  How come it works on one Mac but not the other?  How do I get my beloved 1Password back?

Comment: Have you contacted the makers of 1Password or their support forum?  Since it's a Beta, I'm sure they'd be happy to know of the issue if it hasn't been reported before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when using both 1Password 3 and Evernote toolbar button. I discovered that probably due to a bug in Evernote it just overwrites all additional toolbar buttons, thus my 1Password button were disappearing every time I restarted the Safari. I just removed Evernote button and 1Password button no longer disappears.

Of course I'm looking forward for this behavior to be fixed in the updates to Evernote.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the 1Password button AND the option to customize it with the button disappearing every time I restart Safari. I don't use or even know what Evernote is, so that is not my problem. To fix it for the moment, I have to open 1Password and click  the "remove all extensions" from the browsers in the preferences of 1Password and then click to install them again, and the button shows up. Until the next time I start Safari up.